# Why is the capirally electrophoresis rarely carried out?

Tags: gel-electrophoresis

I'm a student at the university in Japan.
I search details and advantages with each electrophoresis.

I think the capirally electrophoresis has much nice method at the points of resolution, rapidity and so on. However, just my thought, there are not very many of papers using it.

I have asked at a Japanese site (not professional one), and the answer is on cost. But no sites explain so.

Please give me a help for this confusing.
Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Are you asking why capillary electrophoresis is rare compared to normal agarose gel electrophoresis?

Comment: Can you also clarify what kind of analytes you are interested in?

Comment: For WYSIWYG; It is protein. Our laboratory studies it. Except of me, however, none knows capirally's in detail. So the more you teach me, the happier I am.

Comment: For user137; I was going to search in terms of PAGE, but agarose is also OK because I could get few data about the capirally electrophoresis.